# You are trying to create a contract factory from an artifact, but you have not passed a valid artifact parameter

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, react, hardhat-deploy

I'm very new to blockchain development, I've been following along with a tutorial I found online for a basic hello world application using ethers.js, react and metamask.

The repo for the tutorial is [here](https://github.com/mikec3/my_tutorials/tree/master/simple_storage).

The tutorial uses the Remix IDE to compile and deploy and Ganache for the local test.net. However Remix won't load in my browser so I've been using Hardhat for all three.

It seems as if I am able to call the function **setHandler** by entering in some text and hitting the **Update Contract** button.

However, when I try and retrieve information from the contract (by hitting the **Get Current Contract Value**which invokes the **getCurrentVal** function) I get the following error:

```
index.ts:269 Uncaught (in promise) Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="get()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (index.ts:269:1)
    at Logger.throwError (index.ts:281:1)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (interface.ts:427:1)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (index.ts:400:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (index.ts:1:1)
```

I read into this error and it seems by and large this is mostly caused by the contract actually not being deployed on the network (which in this case is my local network).

So I tried redeploying `with npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deploy.js` however this also causes an error:

`NomicLabsHardhatPluginError: You are trying to create a contract factory from an artifact, but you have not passed a valid artifact parameter`.

I am quiet at a loss here in regards what to do as I am not sure where I am going wrong. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated as I have been pulling my hair out over this.

**My Abi**:

```
[
    {
      "anonymous": false,
      "inputs": [
        {
          "indexed": false,
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "eventOutput",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "myEventTest",
      "type": "event"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "get",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "myText",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "name": "set",
      "outputs": [],
      "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [],
      "name": "storedData",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "string",
          "name": "",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    }
  ]
```

**My HelloWorld.js (Main Component that does all the ethers.js work):**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {ethers} from 'ethers';
import HelloWorld_abi from './artifacts/contracts/HelloWorld.sol/HelloWorld.json';

const HelloWorld = () => {

  let contractAddress = "0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9";
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null);
    const [defaultAccount, setDefaultAccount] = useState(null);
    const [connButtonText, setConnButtonText] = useState('Connect Wallet');

    const [currentContractVal, setCurrentContractVal] = useState(null);

    const [provider, setProvider] = useState(null);
    const [signer, setSigner] = useState(null);
    const [contract, setContract] = useState(null);

    const connectWalletHandler = () => {
        if (window.ethereum && window.ethereum.isMetaMask) {

            window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts'})
            .then(result => {
                accountChangedHandler(result[0]);
                setConnButtonText('Wallet Connected');
            })
            .catch(error => {
                setErrorMessage(error.message);

            });

        } else {
            console.log('Need to install MetaMask');
            setErrorMessage('Please install MetaMask browser extension to interact');
        }
    }

    // update account, will cause component re-render
    const accountChangedHandler = (newAccount) => {
        setDefaultAccount(newAccount);
        updateEthers();
    }

    const chainChangedHandler = () => {
        // reload the page to avoid any errors with chain change mid use of application
        window.location.reload();
    }


    // listen for account changes
    window.ethereum.on('accountsChanged', accountChangedHandler);

    window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', chainChangedHandler);

    const updateEthers = () => {
        let tempProvider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
        setProvider(tempProvider);

        let tempSigner = tempProvider.getSigner();
        setSigner(tempSigner);

        let tempContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, HelloWorld_abi, tempSigner);
        setContract(tempContract);
    }

    const setHandler = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('sending ' + event.target.setText.value + ' to the contract');
        contract.set(event.target.setText.value);
    }

    const getCurrentVal = async () => {
        let val = await contract.get();
        setCurrentContractVal(val);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <h4> {"Get/Set Contract interaction"} </h4>
            <button onClick={connectWalletHandler}>{connButtonText}</button>
            <div>
                <h3>Address: {defaultAccount}</h3>
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={setHandler}>
                <input id="setText" type="text"/>
                <button type={"submit"}> Update Contract </button>
            </form>
            <div>
            <button onClick={getCurrentVal} style={{marginTop: '5em'}}> Get Current Contract Value </button>
            </div>
            {currentContractVal}
            {errorMessage}
        </div>
    )
}

export default HelloWorld;
```

**My deploy.js:**

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
  const currentTimestampInSeconds = Math.round(Date.now() / 1000);
  const ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
  const unlockTime = currentTimestampInSeconds + ONE_YEAR_IN_SECS;

  const lockedAmount = hre.ethers.utils.parseEther("1");

  const HelloWorld = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("HelloWorld");
  const helloworld = await HelloWorld.deploy();

  await helloworld.deployed();

  console.log(helloworld.address);
}


main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**And Finally a screenshot of the web app:**
[image]

Comment: First sanity check: The file in the repo is called "SimpleStorage". Your ABI seems to match that file. But in your deploy.js, you're trying to get the "HelloWorld" contract. Did you change the file name to be "HelloWorld"? If not, and the file name is still "SimpleStorage", then you should change into `getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")`.

Comment: Thanks @KenzoAgada, the SimpleStorage part was from the tutorial I was following. It was late and my brain was a bit fried. Find the solution :)